# Stashed files show up as unchanged in `git status` (git v.2.16.0)

Tags: git, git-for-windows

I use git-for-windows v2.16.0 and encountered the following problem, which also was reported [here](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/1437):

I initially have a clean working state; Output of 'git status':

```
git status
On branch beta
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Then I make local changes. Output of `git status`:

```
git status
On branch beta
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   app/src/main/java/android_serialport_api/sample/Debug.java

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Then I stash them with 'git stash':

```
git stash
Saved working directory and index state WIP on beta: 2fca403 working on the console
```

Now my working directory should be clean but the output of `git status` still reads:

```
git status
On branch beta
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   app/src/main/java/android_serialport_api/sample/Debug.java

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Which leads to not being able to `git checkout` etc.

Comment: What version of git are you using? I upgraded to v2.16.0 a week or so ago, and since then I've noticed the same behavior. `git stash` did stash the changes, and the file is reverted (doing a diff shows no changes), but yet the file is still marked as modified.

Comment: v2.16.0. I'm pretty sure I upgraded a week ago when it first released.

Comment: can you check what does git status output before git checkout alpha

Comment: Reported and fixed: https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/1437

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/1437) in Git for Windows and it is fixed in v2.16.0(3). Updating to a newer version will fix this bug.

Thanks to @choroba for pointing out the reported issue!

Answer (score 0):

More recently, stashed files numbers might still not show up, with `git status` using [porcelain v2](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status#_porcelain_format_version_1) ([presented here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51228920/6309))

```
git status --porcelain=v2 --show-stash
```

With Git 2.34 (Q4 2021), it now allows "[`git status --porcelain=v2`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/dea96aae4d4821a7d516257daa6be4be893887cd/Documentation/git-status.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status))</sup>to show the number of stash entries with `--show-stash` like the normal output does.

See [commit 2e59e78](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2e59e78096313920df470b6645a4323e2d8c0c6f), [commit 612942a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/612942a1d201d33c2e952c89d58e5c6d26a028a2) (22 Oct 2021) by [Øystein Walle (`Osse`)](https://github.com/Osse).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit dea96aa](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dea96aae4d4821a7d516257daa6be4be893887cd), 29 Nov 2021)</sup>

> ### [`status`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2e59e78096313920df470b6645a4323e2d8c0c6f): print stash info with `--porcelain=v2 --show-stash`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Øystein Walle</sup>

> The v2 porcelain format is very convenient for obtaining a lot of information about the current state of the repo, but does not contain any info about the stash.
> '[`git status`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/2e59e78096313920df470b6645a4323e2d8c0c6f/Documentation/git-status.txt)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status))</sup> already accepts `--show-stash` but its silently ignored when --porcelain=v2 is given.
>
> Let's add a simple line to print the number of stash entries but in a format similar in style to the rest of the format.

`git status` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/2e59e78096313920df470b6645a4323e2d8c0c6f/Documentation/git-status.txt#L317-L324):

> ### Stash Information
>
> If `--show-stash` is given, one line is printed showing the number of stash
> entries if non-zero:
>
> ## stash